# Lead-lag process control

Tags: control, control-system, pid-controller, controller, process

What is the locus of the following system, and for what value of \$\alpha\$ is the damping ratio 0.5?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried already?  Which bits do you understand?  What bits don't you understand?

Comment: Hi David, I just know that cos(theta) is equal to xi and I should draw the locus and indicate the point on the locus which has angle theta, but I don't know that does it have a unique alpha? and if so, does it have a value?, and if so again, is alpha unique?

Answer (score 1):

You need to first determine the loci with \$\alpha\$ as a parameter, and then choose the value of \$\alpha\$ for which the damping is 0.5. I get it to be 2.8.

[image]

Comment: Thank for editing and your answer.